# Obj-C: Delegate method not getting called

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols

I'm new to iOS Dev, I'm following the Stanford CS193P classes for Fall 2010. I'm on assignment 3 and I'm setting my delegate to my view and by using the debugger I'm noticing the call to my delegate method won't happen, I don't understand what could be happening. My code is as follows:

**GraphViewController.h:**

```
@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController <GraphViewDelegate> {
    GraphView *graphView;
    float scale;
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet GraphView *graphView;
@property float scale;

- (IBAction)zoomIn;
- (IBAction)zoomOut;

@end
```

**GraphViewController.m:**

```
@implementation GraphViewController

@synthesize graphView, scale;

- (NSString *)functionForGraph:(GraphView *)requestor {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"culo peluo");
    return @"lol";
}

- (float)scaleForGraph:(GraphView *)requestor {
    return self.scale;
}

- (IBAction)zoomIn {

}

- (IBAction)zoomOut {

}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.graphView.delegate = self;
    self.scale = 20;
    [self.graphView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

**GraphView.h:**

```
@class GraphView;

@protocol GraphViewDelegate 
- (NSString *)functionForGraph:(GraphView *)requestor;
- (float)scaleForGraph:(GraphView *)requestor;
@end

@interface GraphView : UIView {
    id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (assign) id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**GraphView.m:**

```
@implementation GraphView

@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat cgScale = [self.delegate scaleForGraph:self];
    [AxesDrawer drawAxesInRect:self.bounds originAtPoint:self.center scale:cgScale]; 
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: How do you know it's not calling it? Have you tried adding in a log line to `scaleForGraph:` or set a breakpoint in it? That's the only delegate method that's currently being called.

Comment: Test if delegate is not NIL or deallocated. You are not retaining the delegate because you are using assing property instead of retain.

Comment: Delegates should not generally be retained, as doing so causes a retain cycle. So, assign is correct in this case.

Comment: I know it's not calling it because when debugging it never enters the scaleFromGraph method. And I thought delegates should always be assigned, since they always outlive the object that delegates them, i.e. the controller will always go away after the view. Or am I mistaken? And the delegate does seem to be NIL, don't understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Put a break point on the line where you set the graph view's delegate.
2. Inspect the graphView variable.  Is it nil?

This happens to me all the time and it's always (well nearly always) because I have failed to connect the outlet to the view in interface builder.

Comment: @8vius: As I said, happens to me all the time :)

Comment: In my case it was just a normal method of an external class not being called, and it was because of a n00b error: I called `[instance_var init]` so the `instance_var` was actually `nil`. When I did `[[my_class alloc] init]` it worked. Still trying to workout ARC and iOS.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say class YourClass is a delegate for some other class. And delegate methods are not called, despite that delegate property is set up.

Most probably the problem is that your class instance, that is a delegate for your other class is released before the delegate method is called on it. Make it more persistent by making this class a property or instance variable of other class or by using dispatch_once. For example,

Change

```
YourClass *instance = [[YourClass alloc] init];
```

by

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) YourClass *instance;
self.instance = [[YourClass alloc] init];
```

This problem occurs because in ARC everything that is created inside a method (and is not an instance variable) is released, when method finishes. And delegate methods cannot be called, that are invoked by some background process.

I've written a big blog post on this problem. This is pretty common situation.
http://alwawee.com/wordpress/2013/07/31/on-xmppframework-delegate-method-not-being-called/

Comment: I'd rather not make the instance a class property, but what do you mean by using dispatch_once?

Comment: Thank you, I'm not an iOS developer (I was just doing bridge for react-native) but you explanation made it so clear.

Comment: I'm interested in your article, can you fix the link?

Comment: Thank you . You saved my time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ive got a few pointers for ya on this one:

1. You don't need an iVar (internal Variable) if you have the variable as a property, it will still work, I've never know it not to.

**GraphView**

```
@interface GraphView : UIView {

}

@property (assign) id <GraphViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**GraphViewController**

```
@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController <GraphViewDelegate> {

}

@property (retain) IBOutlet GraphView *graphView;
@property float scale;

- (IBAction)zoomIn;
- (IBAction)zoomOut;

@end
```

1. You need to set your delegate in your view to be able to use it.

**GraphViewController**

```
@implementation GraphViewController

( ... )

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}


( ... )

@end
```

Comment: Here you are saying to set the GraphViewController's delegate to himself. I am setting the delegate from my GraphView in my viewDidLoad method, following some example code (that works) which was provided. Is my approach wrong?

Comment: its a personal choice more then anything, but sometimes you functions in your delegate to be called prior to the ViewDidLoad, in that case it is best to shift it to initialisation not ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the delegate functions anywhere in your `GraphView.m`. Try testing it out by placing this piece of code in your `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method, right before you return.

```
[self.delegate functionForGraph:nil];
```

and see if it logs any message to the console.

Of course this is just to test the delegate implementation, you should actually be using this delegate call in some other method in your `GraphView.m` which is able to process your `requestor`

Comment: I'm calling it in GraphView's drawRect method CGFloat cgScale = [self.delegate scaleForGraph:self];

Comment: If thats the case, try using NSLog or the debugger, to see if the delegate method is being called in your controller object.

Comment: I've used the debugger and it's not getting called, think I'll edit my question to illustrate this better.

Comment: Hmm.. I think the problem might be with you not allocating and initializing your graphView object in your controller's viewDidLoad code. Try putting in self.graphView = [[GraphView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(//your values)];